# ReacticveMongoTemplate and MongoTemplate (blocking) in same application

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-mongodb-reactive

Is configuring `ReactiveMongoTemplate` and `MongoTemplate` (blocking) in the same application can cause problems? Or Can we have reactive and non-reactive mongo configuration in the same application ?